# $(document).ajaxError is not firing on 401

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, chaplinjs

We have an error handler to post the message.

```
 $(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, options) {
  window.postMessage(....);  
});
```

One of the fetch call is returning 401

```
this.fetch = function(url) {
return fetch(url, { 
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
})
```

When I check the response the status is 401 but the response.json() is throwing  " Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input. " Because of this, the ajaxError is not firing.

Expected Behaviour: I want the document.ajaxError to post the message if I don't get the status 200 from the fetch call.

We have an wrapper.js which has overriding function

```
 window.fetch = (function(arg) {


 }(window.fetch)
```

Can I catch this exceptions globally inside of this function?

Comment: I would be surprised if jQuery is able to catch the fetch ajax call error, as it did not originate from jQuery

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uxbcLajt/  yeah, doesn't look like the ajaxError will catch errors from ajax requests not originating from jQuery

Comment: The other thing is that `fetch` won't fail on 401, meaning that it'll go into the `.then` callback. That's counter-intuitive when coming from jQuery's ajax or axios. You should check `response.ok` and if `false`, you need to reject manually.

Comment: @Taplar  I have made an edit to the question description. Do you think this is possible to handle it globally in window.fetch ?

Comment: I'm unclear how that wrapper changes the fact that the ajax is not originating from jQuery.  Edit: It also appears to be a logical error in that you are trying to define a variable, while also trying to pass it into the IIFE meant to define it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments I wasn't able to do it on the ajaxError handler as its not originating from the jquery. 
I was able to do it inside the Window.fetch wrapper

```
 window.fetch = (function (original)) {
  ...............

  return original.apply(this, args).then(function (response)) {

      if(response.status !== 200)
       {
           window.postMessage({ event_type: 'request:failed', status: response.status); 
       }   
   }
}
```